# Linq query to get count

Tags: linq

```
id | IsEnquiry  | 
=================
1      true
2      false
3      false
4      true
```

How can I get the count of id where IsEnquiry=true by using a Linq Query

Pls Help me to write the query.

Thanks,
Bharath

Comment: Table?  Do you really mean LINQ or do you mean SQL? LINQ is for querying language elements ( collections of objects ) not database tables.

Comment: @IanNorton, ever heard of LINQ-to-SQL?

Answer (score 42):

```
int count = (from row in db.Table
             where row.IsEnquiry == true
             select row).Count();
```

Comment: if there are a lot of data in each row, then more effective could be to select something simple instead of the whole row. E.g. (from row in db.Table where row.IsEnquiry select 1).Count();

Answer (score 26):

try this

```
var count = db.Table.Where(x=>x.IsEnquiry).Count()
```

Comment: That's a Lambda expression in a Linq extension, not a Linq Query.
Jared Harding's answer is a Linq query example.

Comment: Oh great Antony, thanks for clearing that up. I was sitting here staring at this like a monkey with a crossword puzzle wondering how to apply this

Comment: Also: `var count = db.Table.Count(x=>x.IsEnquiry);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
int count = (from tableObj in TableName 
             where tableObj
             .Website == "http://mywebsite.com" 
             select tableObj 
             .Website).Count()
```

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
int count = (from row in db.Table
             where row.IsEnquiry == true
             select row.id).Count();
```